# How can i reorder a list by the earliest date in the second column when the first column is the same?

Tags: bash, sorting, perl, awk, sed

I have lots of lists like the following, the first column is an ID number, the second column is a score and the third column is date of birth in DDMMYYYY format.

```
111 100 01012011
222 90 01012001
333 90 01012013
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
```

When there are multiple lines with the same score, i would like to reorder them with the newest date at the top, the result for the example would be:

```
111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
555 80 01012014
444 80 01012015
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
```

As you can see the lines with same scores have been re-arranged with the newest date at the top.

I have first tried to select the earliest date, i can do this with the following:

```
 sort -k1.5 -k1.1,1.2 -k1.3,1.4 | tail -n 1
```

But i am unsure of how i can acheive the outcome.
How can i acheive the result?

Comment: Switch to `YYYYMMDD` format dates and it's trivial.

Comment: You should clarify: do you want dates oldest - newest? Or newest - oldest? Date isn't sorted in your example output (see score 80 and score 90)

Comment: If you want `the newest date at the top` then why does `555 80 01012014` come before `444 80 01012015` in the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with the current `sort` attempt is that you're trying to parse the 1st field (`-k1.`) when what you want is to parse the 3rd field (`-k3.`).

Setup, adding a few entries with dates other than `DDMM == 0101`:

```
$ cat raw.dat
111 100 01012011
222 90 01012001
333 90 01012013
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
aaa 35 01082022
bbb 35 23012022
ccc 35 12112022
ddd 35 10122022
```

One approach, assuming the first sort is for the 2nd field (`score`) in descending numeric order:

```
$ sort -t' ' -k2,2nr -k3.5,3.8nr -k3.3,3.4nr -k3.1,3.2nr raw.dat
111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
ddd 35 10122022
ccc 35 12112022
aaa 35 01082022
bbb 35 23012022
```

Where:

- `-t ' '` - define delimiter as space (overrides default which is the non-blank to blank transition, which would cause leading space(s) to be counted as part of the field)
- `-k2,2nr` - 1st sort (`score`), start with field `2`, end with field `2`, sort as `n`umeric and in `r`everse (aka descending) order
- `-k3.5,3.8nr` - 2nd sort (`YYYY`), start with field `3` and `5`th character, end with field `3` and `8`th character, sort as `n`umeric and in `r`everse order (`-k3.3,3.4nr` and `-k3.1,3.2nr` perform `r`everse `n`umeric sorts on `MM` and `DD`, respectively)
- **NOTE:** OP's expected output shows `ID=555` (`YYYY=2014`) listed before `ID=444` (`YYYY=2015`); I'm assuming this is a typo and that `ID=444` should be listed first

---

Pulling Ed Morton's comments up into this answer ...

- `-b` discards all leading spaces (ie, replaces `-t ' '`) but ...
- the `-b` option must be applied at each key when applying flags at the key level; alternatively ...
- the `-b` option can be applied as a global flag as long as there are no key-level flags (key-level flags take precedence over - and negate - global level flags)

Applying these rules we get one of the following:

```
# all global-level flags

sort -nrb -k2,2 -k3.5,3.8 -k3.3,3.4 -k3.1,3.2 raw.dat

# all key-level flags ('start' only needs '-b` flag)

sort -k2b,2bnr -k3.5b,3.8bnr -k3.3b,3.4bnr -k3.1b,3.2bnr raw.dat

# all key-level flags (overkill on the 'start' flags)

sort -k2bnr,2bnr -k3.5bnr,3.8bnr -k3.3bnr,3.4bnr -k3.1bnr,3.2bnr raw.dat
```

These all generate:

```
111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
ddd 35 10122022
ccc 35 12112022
aaa 35 01082022
bbb 35 23012022
```

Comment: Since the sort is all numeric and the result is reversed the flags may be bundled in with the field delimiter option like so `-nrt' '`

Answer (score 2):

Decorate-sort-undecorate using any versions of these mandatory POSIX tools:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print substr($3,5) substr($3,3,2) substr($3,1,2), $0}' file |
    sort -rn -k3,3 -k1,1 | cut -f2-
111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
```

I'm assuming the posted expected output order for the 2nd col `80`:

```
555 80 01012014
444 80 01012015
```

is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl

```
perl -0777 -wnE'say for 
    map { join " ", @{$_}[0,1], reverse unpack "A4A2A2", $_->[2] } 
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] or $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] } 
    map { 
        my @line = split; 
        [ @line[0,1], join "", reverse unpack "A2A2A4", $line[2] ] 
    } 
    split "\n"
' file
```

Take the whole file (by `-0777`
[switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D)) then split it into lines and feed this into a Schwartzian transform (decorate-sort-undecorate), reversing the date format in the process --

- [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) each line into words and [make a reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut#Making-References) (`[]`) of that list,
  but first "reversing" the date into yyyymmdd format so that it can be later sorted readily
- [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) (numerically) those lines by second-then(or)-third element of their array references
- join back each line, first reversing the date back

I assume that in the end  dates need be in ddmmyyyy format, otherwise adjust.

Or perhaps it's simpler conceptually to first prepare -- read all lines and build an array with array references of their word lists -- and then sort that

```
perl -wnE'
    @ln = split; 
    push @lines, [ @ln[0,1], join "", reverse unpack "A2A2A4", $ln[2] ] 
    }{ 
    say for 
        map { join " ", sprintf "%3d %3d %08d", 
            @{$_}[0,1], join "", reverse unpack "A4A2A2" $_->[2]
        } 
        sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] or $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] }
        @lines
' file
```

where that `}{ ...` syntax starts the `END` block, equivalent to `END { ... }`. All `END` blocks run after all processing in a program has been done (see [perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END)); so here after all lines have been read.  Here I also align output using `sprintf`.

For the stated problem alone on Linux, a solution with system's `sort` is clearly far simpler.
The approach here may be useful when there are other reasons for bringing a programming language in (ie, there is more to do), or if the OS has no tools to do it from command line (Windows).

This doesn't need any system tools, and it is efficient since it pre-processes date-times once, ahead of sorting (and doesn't parse them for every single comparison during sorting).

---

Note: the `444` and `555` pair of lines (with `80` in the second column) in the question is sorted wrong -- it should be first the line with `444` then the line with `555`, not the other way round as shown (by the question's description: "*newest date at the top*")

Comment: Fixed the dates' sorting, as I didn't notice at first that they were "reversed".  This is now yet more complicated but it's portable and efficient (and in a program it'd have to be done a bit like this)

Answer (score 1):

Setup, adding a few entries with dates other than `DDMM == 0101`, added a few rows with duplicate `$2/$3` pairs:

```
$ cat raw.dat
111 100 01012011
222 90 01012001
333 90 01012013
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
aaa 35 01082022     # different DDMM values; should be 3/4
bbb 35 23012022     # different DDMM values; should be 4/4
ccc 35 12112022     # different DDMM values; should be 2/4
ddd 35 10122022     # different DDMM values; should be 1/4
456 40 17052019     # duplicate $2/$3 (and $1); 1/3
123 40 17052019     # duplicate $2/$3         : 2/3
456 40 17052019     # duplicate $2/$3 (and $1); 3/3
```

**NOTE:** comments are included in the file

One `GNU awk` idea:

```
awk '
    { # a [score] [dob as YYYYMMDD] [unique sequence] ; unique sequence required in case score/dob is not unique

      a[$2][substr($3,5,4) substr($3,3,2) substr($3,1,2)][--c]=$0
    }
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"      # sort all indices as numbers in descending order
      for (score in a)
          for (dob in a[score])
              for (seq in a[score][dob])
                  print a[score][dob][seq]
    }
' raw.dat
```

**NOTES:**

- `GNU awk` required for multi-dimensional arrays (aka array of arrays) and `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` support
- in the case of duplicate `$2/$3` pairs we've opted to maintain the input ordering; this could be modified based on additional input from OP on how to proceed in this situation (eg, further ordering by `$1`? remove duplicate lines?)

This generates:

```
111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
456 40 17052019     # duplicate $2/$3 (and $1); 1/3
123 40 17052019     # duplicate $2/$3         : 2/3
456 40 17052019     # duplicate $2/$3 (and $1); 3/3
ddd 35 10122022     # different DDMM values; should be 1/4
ccc 35 12112022     # different DDMM values; should be 2/4
aaa 35 01082022     # different DDMM values; should be 3/4
bbb 35 23012022     # different DDMM values; should be 4/4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Using markp-fuso data
$ cat raw.dat
111 100 01012011
222 90 01012001
333 90 01012013
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
aaa 35 01082022
bbb 35 23012022
ccc 35 12112022
ddd 35 10122022


$ while IFS=" " read -r n s d; do
>    echo "${s}${d:4:4}${d:2:2}${d:0:2} ${n} ${s} ${d}"
> done < raw.dat|sort -nr|cut -d" " -f2-

111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
ddd 35 10122022
ccc 35 12112022
aaa 35 01082022
bbb 35 23012022

$ sed -E 's/(.*) (.*) ([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})/\2\5\4\3 \1 \2 \3\4\5/' raw.dat|sort -nr|cut -d" " -f2-

111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
ddd 35 10122022
ccc 35 12112022
aaa 35 01082022
bbb 35 23012022

awk '
    {
        match($0, /(.*) (.*) ([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})/, m)
        arr[NR]=m[2]m[5]m[4]m[3]" "$0
    }
    END{ 
        asorti(arr, sorted_arr, "@val_num_desc") 
        for (i in sorted_arr){
            row=arr[sorted_arr[i]]
            sub(/^[^ ]* /,"",row)
            print row
        } 
    }
' raw.dat

111 100 01012011
333 90 01012013
222 90 01012001
444 80 01012015
555 80 01012014
666 70 01012016
777 60 01012017
888 50 01012018
ddd 35 10122022
ccc 35 12112022
aaa 35 01082022
bbb 35 23012022
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk:

```
gawk '{split($3, a, ""); print $1,$2,a[5]a[6]a[7]a[8]a[3]a[4]a[1]a[2]}' score-file |
sort -t ' ' -rnk 2,2 -k 3,3 |
gawk '{split($3, a, ""); print $1,$2,a[7]a[8]a[5]a[6]a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4]}'
```

- Split the date in to characters to arrange in largest - smallest units (`ID SCORE YYYYMMDD`).
- This is a format that can be sorted by score then date, with `sort`.
- Specifying multiple `-k` flags to `sort` sorts by those fields, in the order the flags are given (ie sort by field 2, then by field 3).
- `-n` = numeric sort, `-r` = reverse order (high - low), `-t` = field separator (space).
- The second awk rearranges to original format.

If you can get/use input format of `ID SCORE YYYYMMDD` you can trivially sort it with the same sort command (without gawk).

Edit: If you want scores high - low, and dates low - high (old - new), ie. different orders, you can use `sort -t ' ' -k 2,2rn -k 3,3n` in place of the sort command above. `sort` can specify different flags for each key.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my MacOS terminal.
Explanation: I first converted date format to YYMMDD, then sorted.

```
cat input.txt|\
awk '{m=substr($3,1,2);d=substr($3,3,2);y=substr($3,5,4); str=sprintf("%s%s%s",y,m,d);print $1,$2,str}'|\
sort -nrk2,2 -k3,3
```

Comment: DD and MM are switched; this also leaves the dates in the modified form instead of the original form

Comment: My solution is similar to Ed Morton's, if I had paid attention to it, I would not post mine. But you can simply print the original date column and after the sort, just remove the new column I generated. Post here if you need help, but There are plenty of solutions posted already. Good luck.